# How to read csv file by each row and column wise in java without using external jars

Tags: java

Can someone tell me how can i read csv file by each row and column wise in java without using external jars.

I have tried the below code but here i am able to read only one column at a time.

```
public class ParseCSVs{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("./input//SIMNumbers.csv");
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] array = line.split(",");
        System.out.println(array[2]);
    }
}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you aren't reading line by line but everything at once and iterate over the lines. this will break with large files due to massive memory consumption.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you tell me how can i split each row and how can i print particular row data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Java 8 you can use streams. For this there is a `lines` method on the `Files` class. Next you need to `map` from a `String` to a `String[]` which you can then process.

```
public class ParseCSVs{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("./input//SIMNumbers.csv");
        Files.lines(file.toPath(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
             .substream(1)
             .map(line -> Arrays.toList(line.split(",")))
             .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

The code above reads the file line by line, maps the line to a String[] which in turn is turned into a List. This list is finally printed to the console.

Comment: can you please be more specific on how can i print a particular row data. let us say in row1: 1,2,3 columns and row2: 4,5,6. How can i print row2 data.Is possible can you provide me some code snippet

Comment: Hello Deinum i am expecting this. if i have 3  rows with 3 columns suppose if i enter row number 2 i want to get the entire row2 data and print on console

Comment: Then don't use the approach here. Use a `LineNumberReader` and read until the `lineNumber` matches the line you actually want. Use it to read line by line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Scanner class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Here is example from some page from google search: http://www.journaldev.com/2335/how-to-read-csv-file-using-java-scanner-class